# transform.rotate object not rotating with time.deltatime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi guys i am kinda confused, when i do something like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CoinBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {

manager gameManager;
public float speed;
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
        gameManager.coinDown ();
        Destroy (this.gameObject);
    }

}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    gameManager = GameObject.Find ("gameManager").GetComponent<manager> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    transform.Rotate (0f, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0f);
}
}
```

and at the last line in transform.Rotate i dont't use Time.deltaTime it works well and rotates, when i use the deltaTime it doesn't rotate, can someone explain me why it doesn't work and what i need to do to put it working ?:S

Answer (score 3):

I know of two possible reasons why it is not working with `Time.deltaTime`:

**1**.The speed  value is very small. Bump this value up to about 400 and see what happens. This is *likly* the problem.

**2**.You set `Time.timeScale` to `0`. Make sure that this is not `0`. When it is 0, `Time.deltaTime` becomes `0` too. You can check this by putting  `Debug.Log(Time.timeScale);` in the `Update()` function.

Comment: Nice. You can [tick](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer to mark it as solved.